# ¿Cómo se dice "play" en el contexto de música o un DVD?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

En inglés usamos la palabra "play" para significar la acción de ver una película o de escuchar música. La usamos así:

> Can you **play** the movie?
>
> What song is **playing**?

Pregunté un amigo latino y me dijo que no hay una palabra así en español.

¿Me pregunta cuál sería la mejor manera para decir esto en español? ¿Quizás hay una palabra que mi amigo no había escuchado que se puede usar?

Comment: ¿"Un" DVD o "una" DVD? A mí me suena mucho mejor como masculino.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo hice una pregunta de esto [aquí](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/el-uso-de-art%C3%ADculos-con-abreviaturas-como-dvd-cd-o-nombres-de-organizaciones).

Comment: @fedorqui sí, debe ser un DVD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Las palabras que entiendo se usan en lugar `to play` son `reproducir`, `tocar` o `poner` y se usa una u otra según se trate de audio o video y la preferencia o estilo del hablante o según la ocasión. En algunos casos se usan composiciones de `play` con `dar`, `poner`, por ejemplo, `dale play`, `ponle play`.

---

> - ¿Puedes reproducir la película?
> - ¿Puedes poner la película?
> - ¿Puedes ponerle play a la película?

Entiendo que "tocar" no se usa para video.

---

> - ¿Qué canción reproducen?
> - ¿Qué canción tocan?
> - ¿Qué canción está puesta?

En este caso no se usa una composición con `play`.

---

Answer (score 5):

En español no hay solo una palabra para "play", depende del contexto.

> 1.- Can you play the movie?

¿Puedes reproducir/ poner la pelicula?

> 2.- What song is playing?

¿Qué canción está sonando? ¿Qué canción están tocando? ¿Qué canción está puesta?

Answer (score 4):

En español utilizaríamos el verbo "poner".

> ¿Puedes poner esa peli?
>
> ¿Qué canción está puesta?