# Uso de artículos con abreviaturas como DVD, CD o nombres de organizaciones

Tags: uso-de-palabras, abreviaturas, artículos

Esta pregunta viene de un comentario que @fedorqui dejó [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14695/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-play-en-el-contexto-de-m%C3%BAsica-o-una-dvd#comment16766_14695) acerca del uso del artículo con la palabra *DVD*.

Como el español no es mi primer idioma, para mí no hay mucha diferencia entre *la DVD* o *el DVD*.

Entonces, me preguntaba si hay una regla que pueda seguir para decidir el artículo correcto con palabras como *DVD*, *CD*, o nombres de organizaciones así.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sí, la hay.

Hay que expandir la abreviatura (y, si es necesario, traducir el resultado) y entonces decidir cuál es la palabra base e ir con el género y número de esa.

Por ejemplo

> DVD > digital versatile disc > disco versátil digital > disco (masculino y singular)
>
> NASA > National Aeronautics and Space Administration > Administración Nacional de Aeronáutica y Espacio > administración (femenino y singular)

Entonces tenemos **un** DVD pero **la** NASA. Si hay que hacer una abreviatura plural, no se cambia nada excepto las palabras que la modifican, aunque sea común pluralizar las abreviaturas en el habla. Los DVD (plural, *deuvedé* **o** *deuvedés*) o el DVD (singular, solo *deuvedé*).

Comment: La regla es correcta y suele dar buenos resultados; incluso explica por qué la misma abreviatura puede ser masculina o femenina según el país (ej.: el PC o la PC según en ese país sea más habitual decir *ordenador* o *computadora*). Sin embargo, no es una regla universal y tiene algunas excepciones, como las ya lexicalizadas *radar* (detección y medición por radio) o *láser* (amplificación de luz por emisión estimulada de radiación), que son masculinas pese a que su significado sea femenino.

Comment: @Gorpik Es cierto.  Puede que se hayan incorporado a la lengua ya como palabras en vez de como abreviaturas.  Esas dos se lexicalizaron bastante rápidamente en el inglés, dudo que incluso la mayoría de la gente que vivía en la época de su creación las reconozca como abreviaturas. Lo mismo pasa, imagino, con palabras como quásar, púlsar, etcétera que por ser términos jerga pertécnica, suelen tener significados que la gente ignora.

Comment: Tal cual. Como dice [La RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc), _Las siglas adoptan el género de la palabra que constituye el núcleo de la expresión abreviada, que normalmente ocupa el primer lugar en la denominación_.

Answer (score 2):

Como ya se mencionó en la respuesta anterior, no es universal. pero mi recomendación es que en la abreviación que sea, la expandas , como bien dijo nuestro colega, y busques el sustantivo en la frase, eso te dará el género, y su correspondiente artículo.
Por ejemplo , en DVD : disco es el sustantivo y en el caso de NASA: el sustantivo es administración
NBA: asociación es el sustantivo (la NBA)

La cuestión se torna más complicada en situaciones donde está implícito el contexto , por ejemplo : El US. Open y ¿por qué no la US. Open?.
Bueno simplemente porque US. Open **hace referencia** a un torneo y el sustantivo es el que nos dá el genero , y torneo es masculino, por lo tanto se dice El US Open.
Saludos